# Server Based Communication in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls, xcode4.5

Hello I'm using [AMBubbleTableViewController](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMBubbleTableView) which is available on GitHub,Everything is working fine but I could not get scrolled position up to last sent message.How to get last position of scroll.Any help Will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TBXML to parse the response. You can get this from https://github.com/71squared/TBXML

```
**#import "NSDataAdditions.h"**
**#import "TBXML.h"**

 addArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

TBXML *tbxml=[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http: your url will be here"]]];

                TBXMLElement *rootXMLElement=tbxml.rootXMLElement;
                if (rootXMLElement) {
                    TBXMLElement *user=[TBXML childElementNamed:@"RootElement" parentElement:rootXMLElement];
                    while (user!=nil) {

                       TBXMLElement *Record = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"tag1" parentElement:user];
            if(record)
            { 

                        TBXMLElement *ico_img = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"ico_img" parentElement:user];
                        MutableDictionry=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [TBXML textForElement:ico_img],@"ico_img",

                        user = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"Table1" searchFromElement:user];
                        [addArray addObject:MutableDictionry];
                        }
                    }
```

In tableViewCell you can use SDWebImage library to show image. you can download the library from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

**#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%d",indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSString *url= [[addArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ico_img"];
        UserImageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,70, 70) ];
        [UserImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: This answer was valid for the original question. OP has edited the question to change its context, hence the answer is not valid any more

Answer (score 1):

Follow these three steps

1. Write a [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) downloader for connecting to the webservice and downloading the XML.
2. Write the XML parser using [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. Use lazy loading technique described in this [Apple example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) to download the images.

Open source alternatives

1. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) are open source network frameworks which will serve first purpose.
2. [How to choose best XML parser for your application?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) This tutorial mentions the various options available to you for parsing the XML response.
3. For lazy loading of images you can use, [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)(as pointed out in his answer by @Nitin Gohel). This also provides cache.

Since you are a beginner I would recommend starting with the Apple facilitated classes mentioned above to understand the concepts. Then you can go ahead with the alternatives!

Comment: This answer was valid for the original question. OP has edited the question to change its context, hence the answer is not valid any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following demo for Lazy loading :

https://github.com/samspalace/LazyLoading

If you have any query please ask me.

Hope , it will working for you.